# Cassandra Order by currently only support the ordering of columns following their declared order in the PRIMARY KEY

Tags: cassandra

This is the query I used to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE test.comments (msguuid timeuuid, page text, userid text, username text, msg text, timestamp int, PRIMARY KEY (timestamp, msguuid));
```

then I create a materialized view:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW test.comments_by_page AS
    SELECT *
    FROM test.comments
    WHERE page IS NOT NULL AND msguuid IS NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (page, timestamp, msguuid)
    WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (msguuid DESC);
```

I want to get the last 50 rows sorted by timestamp in ascending order.

This is the query I'm trying:

`SELECT * FROM test.comments_by_page WHERE page = 'test' AND timestamp < 1496707057 ORDER BY timestamp ASC LIMIT 50;`

which then gives this error: `InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Order by currently only support the ordering of columns following their declared order in the PRIMARY KEY"`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Is `timestamp` is your primary key column ?

Comment: Your query seems right. but your MV schema is not correct it should be ` CLUSTERING ORDER BY (timestamp ASC, msguuid DESC)`

Comment: When I do that I don't get the last 50 rows. Essentially what I want to do is to grab the last 50 rows inserted, but then sort those results in ascending order. Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: no, you can't natively. But you can fetch the records in reverse order, and then iterate the results in reverse order (that is in asc order)

Comment: Hmm, alright. That's disappointing, but I guess it isn't too big of a deal.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materialized View rules are basically the same of "standard" tables ones. If you want a specific order you must specify that in the clustering key.

So you have to put your `timestamp` into the clustering section.

Answer (score -1):

clustering order statement should be modified as below: 
//Don't forget to put the primary key before timestamp into ()

```
CLUSTERING ORDER BY ((msguuid DESC), timestamp ASC)
```